# Multiply elements of a vector with all elements of same vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to solve a problem in which I want to multiply elements of a vector with all elements of the same vector (also multiplying with self).

I have a working solution for it which is as follows:

```
for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<v.size();j++)
            {
                r.insert(v[i]*v[j]);
            }

        }
```

Here, `v` is the vector in which my elements are stored initially and `r` is the vector in which I am storing the products.

**Problem I am facing**:

It is a O(N^2) algorithm and I want to achieve this in O(N) time. 
Is there any way to achieve this?
Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**

Actually I want to find the nth largest number in the list of numbers that are obtained by multiplying elements of the vector with every other element. 
My approach has been:

1. Find the product and store values in a vector. (Time- O(N^2) ).
2. Sort the vector. (Time - O(N logN) )
3. Find the nth largest number by index access.

I want to improve the N^2 time complexity.

Comment: As far as I can tell this can't be done faster than N^2 because that's the size of the inputs.

Comment: Your result has N\*N elements, correct?  How do you think you can produce N*N numbers in less than O(N^2)?

Comment: Is this your end goal or is this an intermediate step that you think makes sense? As @BenVoigt points out, you are trying to generate an output of size `O(N^2)`. Your algorithm will need time `O(N^2)` to do that. If this isn't the end goal, however, there might be something more clever that can be done.

Comment: @Pradhan I want to find out the nth largest element in the list that contains the product of all the elements of the array. So I decided to multiply all, store in a vector `r`, sort it in descending order, and get the nth element. Any better way of doing this?

Comment: I think it can be done in K log N time, where you are looking for the K-th largest element. Could you update the question please? I will try to post an answer soon. This will allow you to improve over the naive N^2 if either K or N^2 - K is small.

Comment: Might be better to make it a new question since it already has answers.

Comment: @Pradhan, Please post the answer if you have found out. :)

Comment: Your step 2 is actually O(N² logN²), because the vector you're sorting is N² elements large.

Comment: @AkshayArora Your problem can be reduced to the problem of finding the k-th largest element in a "sorted matrix" - something that looks like a Young's Tableau. That should be enough to help you find material online. Sorry, unable to right out a solution now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is avoid computing the same value twice. Indeed, with your solution, all pairs will be multiplied twice. This is best seen if you display the resulting values in a matrix:

```
input: [a, b, c]

output:

aa ba ca
ab bb cb
ac bc cc
```

You can see the symmetry on both sides of the diagonal. This means that when computing the nth column, you only need to compute `size of input - n` values, because the other `n` are already present in the previous columns, where you can retrieve them.

Note that this will have no impact on the complexity of your algorithm, though.

Answer (score 1):

This problem cannot be solved in `O(n)` time in the current formulation, as the output has `O(n^2)` elements.

Comment: However, the code given in the original question does not match the problem described there.

Comment: It does, although ambiguously.

Comment: Thanks for the hint; I will change my answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt My apologies, you have already pointed out before that the desired output contradicts the output size.